# How to convert media file format using API for Android

Tags: java, android, converters, codec

I am looking for an API which can convert media file to any other format eg:- .mp4 to .mp3 in java. I googled around and came accross jave 1.0.2 but still no clue if it can be used to achieve functionality with android project.

If you can share some more information about any API that you have used then it would be of great help.

Comment: The funny thing is that you can simply change extension from mp4 to mp3 and it will work, but this will not remove video information from the file and it would be same size :) There is no API to do it with native android. FFMPEG and SoX are the good start point but you should consider License issue

Comment: i need help in converting .mp3 to .mp4. did you find solution. please share link- S.sadham hussain

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg library for android which will easily convert,crop,edit videos in android. Above is the Link of Library and I am also Adding Commands list you can use to do different Video Functions

**Library**
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android

**List of Commands**
http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

**Commands to Extract Audio from Video**

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.avi -strict experimental -acodec copy /sdcard/videokit/out.mp3

ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 256k -f mp3 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp3
```

Comment: i need help in converting .mp3 to .mp4. did you find solution. please share link. with proper example. m new in this. have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org) library. It's free, open source and well documented.

Link to [Android documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/index.html).

Comment: i need help in converting .mp3 to .mp4. did you find solution. please share link. with proper example. m new in this. have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder

This seems to work. But the source code is not there.

Comment: i need help in converting .mp3 to .mp4. did you find solution. please share link. with proper example. m new in this.  have no idea what to do- C Luo