# Android - Check if video file is .mp4. Convert it to .mp4 if not

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediacodec

In my app a user selects a video from their camera roll. I need to check if that video is in a `.mp4` container format and if it is not, I need to convert it to `.mp4`.

Is there a modern way to do this today in Android?

Some of the things I tried:

I tried reading the mimeType from the `File` with `String mimeType = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE)`. But I think this may not be accurate because I am not actually looking at the codecs in the file. The mimeType could be inaccurate.

It looks like people are saying to use [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605029) to convert the file to `.mp4`, but the library listed is 7 years old and it seems overkill to use an external library for this. Is there a way modern way to do this with Android?

Comment: Why not the old way inspecting first few bytes? https://www.file-recovery.com/mp4-signature-format.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIME type reported by a `MediaMetadataRetriever` is usually correct. If it says `video/mp4` then the container is likely MP4.

You can double check it using a `MediaExtractor`:

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(context, fileUri, null);
PersistableBundle metrics = extractor.getMetrics();
String format = metrics.getString(MediaExtractor.MetricsConstants.FORMAT);
String mime = metrics.getString(MediaExtractor.MetricsConstants.MIME_TYPE);
```

Note that this doesn't tell you what codecs were used to compress the video / audio tracks (`H.264`, `H.265`, etc.). For this you would need to look at the MIME type of the track.

```
MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(trackIndex);
```

A low-code solution for transcoding is to use a library such as [Media3 Transformer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/transformer).